# Code Blocks and Gtkmm on Ubuntu 14.04TLA

Tags: c++, c, ubuntu, gtkmm

I downloaded Ubuntu 14.04TLS recently.
I'm very new to the Linux environment as I'm a Windows user. I don't really know how to install application on the Linux environment.
please I need help on how to get code blocks with MinGW for Ubuntu and how to configure it.
Also I need help on how to install gtkmm and configure code block to locate it.
I don't know if the same way we do

1. Open Project > Build Options…
2. Select your project.
3. On the Compiler settings tab, select Other options
   and add this to the field:
   `pkg-config gtkmm-3.0 –cflags`
4. Select the Linker settings tab and type the following
   line in the Other linker options text area:
   `pkg-config gtkmm-3.0 –libs`

that we will also do for Ubuntu. Also are we doing anything about environment variable.
also if you can recommend tutorials that I can use to understand the Ubuntu environment properly.
thank you once again

Answer (score 0):

install code blocks on linux ubuntu (mingw is windows version of gcc)

```
sudo apt-get install codeblocks build-essential
```

install gtkmm

```
sudo apt-get install libgtkmm-3.0-dev
```

Comment: thanks TerryG.
please do you also write C++ applications on Linux.
if you do. what tutorials or YouTube video channel can you advice me to properly learn C++ and gtkmm.
I'm very new to software dev.
Also I don't know if I can get. your email or send you mine so that you can at least be my mentor or something.

Comment: i am just learning C sorry i have not looked much at C++ yet, glad to have been of help

Comment: ok. terry.
but don't you have guys who are into C++ who will be very kind enough to help me.

Comment: I don't think it would be right of me to assume my friends want to be your teachers

Answer (score 0):

This is everything you need to know:
https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&ei=6f8EVILBHYjBOP35gOAN&url=http://dottonetto.com/home/wp-content/uploads/2012/02/Programming-with-gtkmm-3.pdf&cd=1&ved=0CBsQFjAA&usg=AFQjCNEAIkFNCENMdOh0VvUo4zmDymL9cw&sig2=HKTiOjNFUdauvTGIQUlnhQ

Comment: Providing an excerpt of an article with the answer would be infinitely more beneficial.