# Set up gtkmm-3.0 in Code::Blocks on linux for C++ GUI appz

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, codeblocks, gtkmm

I'm a beginning C++ programmer and want to use Code::Blocks IDE on Debian based Linux to write some GUI programs.

Therefore I would like to use gtkmm 3.0 with this code:

```
#include <gtkmm/gtkmm.h>
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  auto app = Gtk::Application::create(argc, argv, "org.gtkmm.examples.base");
  Gtk::Window window;
  window.set_default_size(200, 200);
  return app->run(window);
}
```

The compiler gives me this error:

```
fatal error: gtkmm/gtkmm.h: No such file or directory
```

I followed these steps to install gtkmm:

1. Installed Code::Blocks and was able to compile non-GUI programs.
2. Then installed gtkmm-3.0 with synaptic.
3. In Code::Blocks settings > compiler > compiler settings > other compiler options I set:

   pkg-config --cflags gtk+-3.0
4. In codeblock settings > compiler> linker settings > other linker settings I set:

   pkg-config --libs gtk+-3.0
5. When compiling I got the next error in Build log:

   ```
   Build file: "no target" in "no project" (compiler: unknown)
   [ 50.0%] g++ -std=c++14 -pthread -I/usr/include/gtk-3.0 -I/usr/include/at-spi2-atk/2.0 -I/usr/include/at-spi-2.0 -I/usr/include/dbus-1.0 -I/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dbus-1.0/include -I/usr/include/gtk-3.0 -I/usr/include/gio-unix-2.0 -I/usr/include/cairo -I/usr/include/libdrm -I/usr/include/pango-1.0 -I/usr/include/harfbuzz -I/usr/include/pango-1.0 -I/usr/include/fribidi -I/usr/include/atk-1.0 -I/usr/include/cairo -I/usr/include/pixman-1 -I/usr/include/uuid -I/usr/include/freetype2 -I/usr/include/libpng16 -I/usr/include/gdk-pixbuf-2.0 -I/usr/include/libmount -I/usr/include/blkid -I/usr/include/glib-2.0 -I/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/glib-2.0/include  -c /home/meltdown/Documents/C++/GTKmm2019C/t1/t1.cpp -o /home/meltdown/Documents/C++/GTKmm2019C/t1/t1.o
   [100.0%] g++  -o /home/meltdown/Documents/C++/GTKmm2019C/t1/t1 /home/meltdown/Documents/C++/GTKmm2019C/t1/t1.o  -lgtk-3 -lgdk-3 -lpangocairo-1.0 -lpango-1.0 -latk-1.0 -lcairo-gobject -lcairo -lgdk_pixbuf-2.0 -lgio-2.0 -lgobject-2.0 -lglib-2.0  
   /home/meltdown/Documents/C++/GTKmm2019C/t1/t1.cpp:2:10: fatal error: gtkmm/gtkmm.h: No such file or directory
       2 | #include <gtkmm/gtkmm.h>
         |          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
   compilation terminated.
   Process terminated with status 1 (0 minute(s), 0 second(s))
   1 error(s), 0 warning(s) (0 minute(s), 0 second(s))
   ```

I use a single .cpp file, not a Gtk+ project.

I've tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25581765/code-blocks-and-gtkmm-on-ubuntu-14-04tla) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5921460/how-to-setup-gtk-to-develop-with-codeblocks-on-ubuntu-linux) but no luck.  Does anyone know how to set up Code::Blocks and its compiler properly for gtkmm?

Comment: Do you have gtkmm installed?

Comment: Yes, installed 3.0 with the package manager.

Comment: You might want to list what you've actually done instead of linking to directions. (You could keep the links as references, but let's entertain the possibility that you did not follow the directions perfectly.) In addition, there are two pieces of information that could be useful. First, the compile command. You may need to switch your output tab from "Build messages" to "Build log" to get it. Second, everything that is listed under `Project` (menu) `-> Build Options...` (submenu) `-> Compiler settings` (tab, should be the default) `-> Other compiler options` (tab).

Comment: Edited the question.

Answer (score 2):

You've asked the IDE to search include directories for the GTK+ package with the command:

```
`pkg-config --cflags gtk+-3.0`
```

However, your program uses gtkmm, which is a layer on top of GTK+. You want to broaden the search to encompass the directories for gtkmm:

```
`pkg-config --cflags gtkmm-3.0`
```

(This replaces the current entry in the "other compiler options".) Similarly, you'll need to change, under "other linker settings", the library paths to:

```
`pkg-config --libs gtkmm-3.0`
```

Comment: Changed the commands in Code::Blocks and added two ` around each command.  Also the include had to be: #include <gtkmm-3.0/gtkmm.h>.  Now I am able to compile.  Thanks for the answer and the editing.

Comment: Right, I should put the ticks in the answer for the next person.